# react-day-picker - disabledDays does not work when using in DayPickerInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-day-picker

I found the code below in [this page](http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/disabled/):

```
<DayPicker
  initialMonth={new Date(2017, 3)}
  disabledDays={[
    new Date(2017, 3, 12),
    new Date(2017, 3, 2),
    {
      after: new Date(2017, 3, 20),
      before: new Date(2017, 3, 25),
    },
  ]}
/>
```

I am trying to apply it ( re disabledDays ) to my case (i.e. when using 'DayPickerInput', not 'DayPicker') as follows:

```
<DayPickerInput
  // ...
  disabledDays: {
    before: pydate.toDate(),
    after: date,
  },
/>
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that it should be as follows:

```
<DayPickerInput
  // ...
  dayPickerProps={{
    enableOutsideDays: false,
    disabledDays: {
      before: pydate.toDate(), // pydate is generated using moment.js
      after: date,  // date is generated using new Date(...)
    },
  }}
/>
```

Hope it helps someone.